# Run current file as PHP script

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to run current *.php file as PHP script from within Visual Studio Code? Information I've found suggests you can *debug* code if you install Xdebug but it feels weird you can't just *run* code.

<sub>(This was a standard feature in all editors around year 2000 but it's becoming harder to find nowadays...)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the editor doesn't have such feature because there's a third-party extension that implements it...You need to install [Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattn.Runner). Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> launches the script in the *Output* pane:

[image: screenshot]

PHP is configured [out of the box](https://github.com/mattn/vscode-runner/blob/de9ffdbbbeb11f321a7220156501142266f1f094/src/extension.ts#L13):

```
const defaultLanguageMap = {
  bat: '',
  clojure: 'clj',
  go: 'go run',
  javascript: 'node',
  lua: 'lua',
  perl6: 'perl6',
  perl: 'perl',
  php: 'php',
  powershell: 'powershell -noninteractive -noprofile -c -',
  python: 'python',
  r: 'Rscript',
  ruby: 'ruby',
  shell: 'bash',
  typescript: 'tsc'
};
```